# subprocess error while running an external python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a script "test.py" as below but running into the following error.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
verifygerritscmd = ("python test.py --InputFile=list.txt --Project=location/code --branch=master")
gerritPipe = Popen(verifygerritscmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error) = gerritPipe.communicate()
if error != "":
    print error
    raise IOError, "gerrit command %s failed" % (gerritCmd)
print output
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_anoop.py", line 4, in <module>
    gerritPipe = Popen(verifygerritscmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single
> string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args
> if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is
> platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable
> arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless
> otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

Which means that you need to do this:

```
verifygerritscmd = ("python test.py --InputFile=list.txt --Project=location/code --branch=master").split()
```

To create a list of args. Or you can specify `shell=True` in the Popen constructor.

```
gerritPipe = Popen(verifygerritscmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

---

Also you should make sure that your path is correct. When using the subprocess module it is best not to be ambigous about the paths you use. so calling "test.py" should probably be changed to "/path/to/test.py"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set parameter shell=True:

```
 gerritPipe = Popen(verifygerritscmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

explanation: without that you try to execute script that is named `python test.py ...`

You can also try to define verifygerritscmd as list:

```
verifygerritscmd = ['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py', 'argument1', 'argument2' ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). **If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.**